# Rotate text next to right brace in multirow environment

Tags: tables, rotating, multirow

The following LaTeX creates a simple table with some rows grouped with a right curly brace:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
...
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|r}
\hline
$a$ &  $b$ & x&\\
\hline
$cccccc$ & $dddddd$ & x& 
\multirow{3}{*}{}
\rdelim\}{3}{1cm}[long text here]\\
$eeeeee$ & $fffffffff$ &x&\\
$gggggg$ & $hhhhhhhhh$ &x&\\
\end{tabular}
```

How do I rotate `long text here` 90 degrees so that it renders vertically>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package, as suggested in most of the related questions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|r}
  \hline
  $a$ & $b$ & x&\\
  \hline
  $cccccc$ & $dddddd$ & x& \multirow{3}{*}{}
  \rdelim\}{3}{1cm}[{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\ long text here\ }}]\\[4mm]
  $eeeeee$ & $fffffffff$ &x&\\[4mm]
  $gggggg$ & $hhhhhhhhh$ &x&\\[4mm]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the solution with the `bigdelim` package doesn't seem to work in case  `\arraystretch` or any  rowspacing modifier (`\extrarowheight` or the `\cellspace` package) is used.
I have a solution with the `blkarray` package that seems to works well (the last image below). The three methods are illustrated below. They  use `\rotatebox` + `\raisebox`; this one helps placing the rotated tex correctly, and makes latex believe it has 0pt width and 0pt height:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}

        \usepackage{graphicx, mathtools}
        \usepackage{array, multirow, bigdelim}%
        \usepackage{blkarray} 

        \begin{document}

        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|@{}r}
        \cline{1-3}line
        $a$ &  $b$ & x&\\
        \cline{1-3}
        $cccccc$ & $dddddd$ & x&
        \multirow{3}{*}{}
        \rdelim\}{3}{0.4cm}\raisebox{\dimexpr -0.5\totalheight +0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize long text here}}
        \\%
        $eeeeee$ & $fffffffff$ &x&\\
        $gggggg$ & $hhhhhhhhh$ &x&\\
        \cline{1-3}
        \end{tabular}
        \\[1cm]

         \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|@{}r}
        \cline{1-3}line
        $a$ &  $b$ & x&\\
        \cline{1-3}
        $cccccc$ & $dddddd$ & x&
        \multirow{3}{*}{}
        \rdelim\}{3}{0.4cm}\raisebox{\dimexpr -0.5\totalheight +0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize long text here}}
        \\%
        $eeeeee$ & $fffffffff$ &x&\\
        $gggggg$ & $hhhhhhhhh$ &x&\\
        \cline{1-3}
        \end{tabular}
        \\[1cm]

        \begin{blockarray}{|l|l|l|@{}r}%
        \cline{1-3}\text{line}
        $a$ &  $b$ & x&\\
        \cline{1-3}
        \begin{block}{|l|l|l|r\Right{\}}{\raisebox{\dimexpr -0.5\totalheight +0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize long text here}}}}
        $cccccc$ & $dddddd$ & x&
        \\%
        $eeeeee$ & $fffffffff$ &x&\\
        $gggggg$ & $hhhhhhhhh$ &x&
        \\
        \end{block}
        \cline{1-3}
        \end{blockarray}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While spacings between the rows are set by the use of optional argument of `\\\` command, it still doesn't work properly. Is it a possibility of shorting braces to obtain a 1 mm space between them (while the spacings between the following rows have default width; [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129661/how-can-i-put-some-white-space-between-consecutive-bigdelim-braces-in-tabular-w))? I am rather interested in use of `longtable` environment.